# Help finding robot tracks

Tags: mobile-robot, tracks

I have a Robot with tracks. One of the tracks broke and I need to find a replacement, the tracks use the same plastic interconnects/pieces as this:

[image]

They were very popular years back. Does anyone know the brand/name?

Comment: Can You edit your question and add your tracks photos?

Comment: same plastic type treds as in photo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a shopping recommendation question.

Comment: This is an identification question @mactro rather than a *[shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)*. It's aim is not an opinion on what to buy, it is a *[practical, answerable question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* about the manufacturer of this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found them on Pololu. Still don't know the exact manufacturer but I digress...

https://www.pololu.com/product/2074

Answer (score 1):

This image appears to be coming from [here](http://www.robotshop.com/blog/en/johnny-robot-gm-track-kit-b-jpg).

This "johnny robot gm track kit" is now sold as "[Standard GM Track Kit](http://www.robotshop.com/eu/en/standard-gm-track-kit-axles.html)":

Or at least it looks very similar.

Comment: Those have treads on it. And indeed that was where i got my picture from. I just believe the name of the manufacturer was taimya or something but cant find anything to the effect. they were very popular.

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by "treads"? Do you mean the profile on the surface? With a bit of sandpaper and like 10 minutes of work, this should be gone.